# typo3 flow ldap authentication

Tags: php, ldap, typo3, typo3-flow

Is there any good tutorial on how to make the flow ldap authentication work?
i already looked at this: http://docs.typo3.org/flow/TYPO3FlowDocumentation/TheDefinitiveGuide/PartIII/Security.html
and currently i'm trying to work with this concept.
https://packagist.org/packages/typo3/ldap
but it does not seem to work anyhow.
I am able to connect correctly to the ldap/ad server without any excepptions but i'm not able to login with any user provided usually from that server.

Any good examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be more specific about the steps you already took to achieve LDAP login. Did you implement the methods documented in https://git.typo3.org/Packages/TYPO3.LDAP.git/blob/HEAD:/Documentation/Index.rst? Does the login form work, does the submit of the form return anything?

You might first check your LDAP log on the LDAP server if it gets any request at all. The information provided by the LDAP log helps you to spot the problem easily; may it be problems with encryption or something else.